# ASP .Net Get Current User ID from SQL Server Compact database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I have a page that I'm trying to identify the current user's id key so that I can insert additional information for a new table. I've included the code for the page that works in SQL Server Express, but I think that there is a reference issue on the binding to identify the `@UserID`.

Any thoughts?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlServerCe" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Linq" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Permissions" %>

<script language="c#" runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void UserProfileDataSource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

        //MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        //string UserID = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        //e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = UserID;

        // Get a reference to the currently logged on user
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();

        // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        // Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter
        e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUserId;
    }

    protected void UserProfile_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsUpdatedMessage.Visible = true;
    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <h2>Update Your Settings</h2>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="SettingsUpdatedMessage" runat="server" Text="Your settings have been updated." EnableViewState="false" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </p>

    <!-- 
             ProviderName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" -->
    <asp:DetailsView ID="UserProfile" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="UserId" 
        DataSourceID="UserProfileDataSource" DefaultMode="Edit" 
        onitemupdated="UserProfile_ItemUpdated">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HomeTown" HeaderText="HomeTown" 
                SortExpression="HomeTown" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HomepageUrl" HeaderText="HomepageUrl" 
                SortExpression="HomepageUrl" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Signature" HeaderText="Signature" 
                SortExpression="Signature" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserProfileDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
             ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection.ProviderName %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [UserId], [HomeTown], [HomepageUrl], [Signature] FROM [UserProfiles] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)" 
        onselecting="UserProfileDataSource_Selecting" UpdateCommand="UPDATE UserProfiles SET
    HomeTown = @HomeTown,
    HomepageUrl = @HomepageUrl,
    Signature = @Signature
WHERE UserId = @UserId
">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="HomeTown" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="HomepageUrl" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Signature" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

I keep getting the error:

> System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from DbType Object to a known SqlDbType.

I think it is related to the `UserProfileDataSource_Selecting`, but I'm not sure. I can't find an equivalent SQL Server CE reference to use.

Comment: it seems there is no SqlDbType for GUID supported by CE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceparameter.sqldbtype(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: I thought that might be possible.  I appreciate you including the link, but I am not quite sure how to implement your suggestion. Would you mind showing a little script on implementation based on the code provided above.  I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Managed Data Type Mappings (SQL Server Compact)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174642.aspx) by comparison to [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) it seems that `Object` is not a valid `DbType` and can not be mapped to `SqlDbType` in **SQL Server Compact** (but is valid in **SqlServer**).

Since *Userid* is a `Guid`, try to replace:

```
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
</SelectParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="HomeTown" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="HomepageUrl" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="Signature" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

With :

```
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" DbType="Guid" />
</SelectParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="HomeTown" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="HomepageUrl" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="Signature" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" DbType="Guid" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: Thanks,  doing that I get this error: "Cannot create an object of type 'System.TypeCode' from its string representation 'Guid' for the 'Type' property. AdditionalUserInfo.aspx"

Comment: System.Guid?  Not sure I follow you.  Sorry... not trying to be dense.  This does not work: 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.GUID" %>

Comment: <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="System.GUID" />
Does not work either

Comment: Chris, that seems to have resolved the error.  When the users were entered into the db, they did not have values for this record.  Is there a way to show the form if the record count for the select statement is zero?  Right now, the page is coming up (meaning no error) but it is completely blank in the body (meaning no form values).    I did log in via several of the log ins.  The only one the form came up was for the one that I entered myself with the additional user information in the profile.  You can't add new information to this form if the data does not exist currently.

Comment: @user2511441 are you able to do this with sqlserver? I have re updated my answer since maybe the update command also fails.

Comment: Chris, I just tried with the UserId without the dbtype="Guid" and the update worked. I think I need to ask new question as I believe what I need is to insert a blank record for the user if one can be found on page load.  Not sure how to mark this as complete as this is my first question here.

Comment: Thank you chris and everyone for helping out on this.

Comment: Chris, the only problem I'm having now is that the form fields are showing up twice.  I went to the datasource and found that there was only one record.  On the select statement, I've added a Distinct with no change.

Comment: @user2511441 Concerning the parameters, you mean you need to set `dbtype="Guid"` for `select` command and not for `update` command? or not at all? Let me know in order to correct the answer if needed. I was able to put you on the road concerning the first error you was having, since I have some knowledge in SQLCE. But I have none in ASP.NET and I am afraid not being able to help you more on this last question.